# How to make a class garbage collect its attributes or data when its instance is set to None?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, object, garbage-collection

I am trying to unittest a html parser which holds elements after parsing.
But when I create another instance of class it inherits all the elements which first parser had stored.

I have tried to use `del` or tried to set first instance to `None`. But neither of them have gotten rid of elements passing right off to each other.

This is an very short demo of what I had in my code.

```py
class Base:
    stack = []

    def parse(self):
       pass

class Page(Base):
   def get(url):
       pass

pg = Page()
pg.get(url)
pg.parse()
pg.stack    # => [Element(), Element()]


class TestWebPageElements(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.pg = Page()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.pg = None

    def test_parsing(self):
       self.pg.get(url)
       self.pg.parse()
       self.pg.stack    # => [Element(), Element()]


class TestWebPageElements2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.pg = Page()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.pg = None

    def test_parsing(self):

       # XXX: Here the stack is already filled why?

       self.pg.stack    # => [Element(), Element()]
```

I expect the stack to be empty on the second unittest because its a new object. But it doesn't.

Comment: The `stack` variable is a class-attribute (as opposed to an object-attribute) it shared between all objects of that class. It will not be garbage collected. You should make it an object-attribute (`self.stack`).

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case.